# Organize list of object in java

Tags: java

I have a class

```
public class ProductStock {

   private Long id;
   private Integer quantity;

}
```

and a list like

```
List<ProductStock> productStocks = 
{
  ProductStock(1, 1),
  ProductStock(2, 1),
  ProductStock(3, 1),
  ProductStock(1, 1),
  ProductStock(4, 1),
  ProductStock(5, 1),
  ProductStock(2, 1)
}
```

I want to group productStocks by id.
What is the best way to convert this list like bellow

```
productStocks = 
{
  ProductStock(1, 2),
  ProductStock(2, 2),
  ProductStock(3, 1),
  ProductStock(4, 1),
  ProductStock(5, 1)
}
```

Comment: Use Java8 streams and a map. Besides that "best" is quite vague but in any case you might want to try something yourself.

Comment: Use a map and aggregate them there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it that way:

```
Map<Long, Integer> counting = productStocks.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(ProductStock::getId, Collectors.counting()));
```

Create an new Map with the id as key and the Count as value.

Comment: One note though: `Collectors.counting()` will _count_ the products not aggregate the quantities. Try with initial quantities other than 1.

Answer (score 4):

With Java8 streams you could try it like this:

```
productStocks = new ArrayList<>( productStocks.stream().collect( 
       Collectors.toMap( p -> p.id, p -> p, (p,o) -> { p.quantity += o.quantity; return p;} ) )
                 .values() );
```

What this does:

- `productStocks.stream().collect( Collectors.toMap(...) )` creates a stream for the list and collects the values into a map.
- `p -> p.id` uses the product's id as the map key
- `p -> p` uses the product as the map value, if it doesn't exist already
- `(p,o) -> { p.quantity += o.quantity; return p;}` merges the existing product `p` and the "new" product value `o` by adding the quantity into `p` and returning that. Alternatively you could create a new `Product` instance: `(p,o) -> new Product(p.id, p.quantity + o.quantity)`
- finally we build a new list out of the map's values

Note that collecting the elements into a map like like might not preserve the order of the elements. If you want to keep the order as defined in the source list, you could add a 4th parameter to `collect(...)`: `LinkedHashMap::new`.

Answer (score 4):

You can group the products by iterating the List and add products to LinkedHashMap to preserve order:

```
void mergeProducts() {
    Map<Long, Integer> pMap = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
    for (ProductStock ps :  productStocks) {
        if (pMap.containsKey(ps.getId())) {
            int qty = pMap.get(ps.getId());
            qty += ps.getQuantity();
            pMap.put(ps.getId(), qty);
        } else {
            pMap.put(ps.getId(), ps.getQuantity());
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Product grouping: ");
    for (Map.Entry<Long, Integer> entry : pMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Map` for aggregating all the `ProductStock` in one place. Then you can use the contents of this `Map` to create the new `List` of `ProductStock` that will have the aggregated data.

```
Map<Long, Long> productStockMap = productStocks.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductStock::getId, Collectors.counting()));
productStocks = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map.Entry<Long, Long> entry: productStockMap.entrySet()) {
    productStocks.add(new ProductStock(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().intValue()));
}
```

Result:

```
============Before============

ProductStock{id=1, quantity=1}
ProductStock{id=2, quantity=1}
ProductStock{id=3, quantity=1}
ProductStock{id=1, quantity=1}
ProductStock{id=4, quantity=1}
ProductStock{id=5, quantity=1}
ProductStock{id=2, quantity=1}

=============After============

ProductStock{id=1, quantity=2}
ProductStock{id=2, quantity=2}
ProductStock{id=3, quantity=1}
ProductStock{id=4, quantity=1}
ProductStock{id=5, quantity=1}
```

Comment: Note: due to auto(un)boxing instead of `(int)entry.getValue().intValue()` you can write only `entry.getValue()` but even without that the cast to `int` should not be necessary.